# Woman watches scientists stack a pyramid made of small cubes

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to track down a film I saw in my childhood on TV in the UK.

- Most likely this would have been broadcast between 1983 and 1986 as I am fairly sure it was part of the "Murder Mystery Suspense" themed slot channel 3 ran on Saturday evenings.
- Most of these were US made for TV films and very few would have had any science fiction content.
- I probably saw the trailer for this one and thought it looked science fiction-ish and wanted to watch it. Almost certainly I did not see it to the end.
- I cannot say for certain that it was SF and would like to find out.
- I remember one scene: a woman is watching a projected film of what I recall as white, lab-coated scientists using remote manipulator arms to stack up small black or grey cubes into a pyramid shape. Then something goes wrong, so red lights and alarms flash. The woman shivers.

Comment: It is possible that the small cubes remotely manipulated could be fissionable material being assembled into a reactor.  If so the story could be a realistic story about an atomic accident or a science fiction story.

Comment: @M.A.Golding yes, its a possibility but my google searches for that have not turned up anything yet... I'll keep hunting though, I might get lucky yet.